# SPF Softfail: domain of transitioning discourages use of IP

Tags: email, smtp

I have some emails that are being softfailed with the following in the email header:

received-spf: SoftFail (protection.outlook.com: domain of transitioning
mail.mydomain.com discourages use of 194.104.110.241 as permitted sender)

What I have noticed is that IP 194.104.110.241 is not the original sender IP, but Mimecast.

Received: from de-smtp-1.mimecast.com (194.104.110.241).

Looks like the original email is relayed via MimeCast to Outlook and then Outlook Softfail the email.

Question is, is there anything that I can do from my domain mydomain.com to prevent this softfail?

I do not want to just go and add mimecast in my SPF record.